# How to loop the query in this case?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have been trying to loop this query but all I get is the first value.

When I do the same command in workbench I get all the values.
What am I doing wrong here? Any answers are much appreciated!

```
global $db;
$stmt12 = $db->query('SELECT `Value` FROM overriddenpropertyvalues WHERE ParentGUID LIKE "' . $itemguid . '";');
$propertyvaluerow = $stmt12->fetch();
while ($propertyvaluerow != null) {
```

Comment: You're code is broken. Please add the rest of it and also include any errors you're getting

Comment: it wouldn't be much use to you since you can't run it without the database anyway. I have this query inside a public static function. the problem is that this code is not returning any array of values and I was wondering if anyone can spot something off.

Comment: use `fetchAll()` instead of `fetch()` =>  `$propertyvaluerow = $stmt12->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching only one value with `->fetch()`. That's why you receive only one value.

Example from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php):

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT `Value` FROM `overriddenpropertyvalues` WHERE ParentGUID LIKE :like');

$query->execute([':like' => $itemguid]);

$stmt->bind_result($value);

while ($query->fetch()) {
    echo $value."<br/>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might possibly be a loophole in your Program depending on what the **$stmt12->fetch()** does. If it fetches an Array of Data, your while loop might not behave as expected. Below is a commented alternative to what you might want to try out:

```
    <?php
        global $db;
        $stmt12         = $db->query('SELECT `Value` FROM overriddenpropertyvalues WHERE ParentGUID LIKE "' . $itemguid . '";');
        // ASSUMES YOU ARE USING PDO SO WE FETCH ALL THE DATA
        $propertyvaluerow = $stmt12->fetchAll();

        // THERE MIGHT BE A LOOPHOLE IN YOUR PROGRAM DEPENDING ON WHAT $stmt12->fetch() IS AND DOES
        // ASSUMING IT FETCHES AN ARRAY OF NESTED OBJECTS OR SCALAR VALUES, THE WHILE LOOP WOULD NOT BEHAVE AS EXPECTED.
        // THAT MEANS IF IT IS AN ARRAY YOU COULD USE A DIFFERENT CONSTRUCT LIKE THE ONE BELOW YOUR WHILE CONSTRUCT:
        /* while ($propertyvaluerow != null) { */

        // CREATE A $count VARIABLE TO HOLD THE INCREMENTAL COUNT THROUGH THE ITERATION:
        $count  = count($propertyvaluerow);

        while($count > 0){
            // DO YOUR WORK HERE

            //DECREMENT THE VALUE OF COUNT OTHERWISE YOU MAY HAVE AN INFINITE LOOP TO DEAL WITH.
            $count--;
        }

    ?>
```

There is yet another alternative:

```
   <?php            
        // OR EVEN A MUCH MORE EASIER WAY IS TO USE THE FOREACH LOOP, WHICH ACHIEVES THE SAME THING AS THE WHILE LOOP:
        foreach($propertyvaluerow as $iKey=>$objData){
            // SIMPLY USE THE $objData IN WITHING THE LOOP
            // THE $objData IS THE VALUE OF THE CURRENT OBJECT IN THE $propertyvaluerow IN THE ITERATION
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way:

```
global $db;
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `Value` FROM OverriddenPropertyValues WHERE ParentGUID=?');
$stmt->execute([$itemguid]);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($rows as $row) {
    // $row->Value or $row['Value']
}
```